# How is the realm value set in HTTP basic authentication?

Tags: linux, http, authentication, iot

I have a D-Link (DCS-932L) web camera in my network.  I have unpacked the firmware using binwalk and I am attempting to locate the config/file that populates the realm value but I cannot find any place where that data seems to be pulled from.

resulting curl command displays the realm information as:

```
HTTP/1.0 401 Authorization Required
Server: alphapd
Date: Wed Feb 01 05:11:53 2019
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-type: text/html
Content-length: 103
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="DCS-932L"
```

Is there a file or location that the HTTP Basic realm information is typically pulled from, that I could look at within the firmware on Linux-based IoT devices?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing unique about the realm, it is part of **the website's configuration** just as much as the usernames/passwords it'll accept or the URLs/pages that it'll serve, and there is no globally standard location for such configuration, neither in IoT nor Linux-based HTTP servers in general.

By "the website" here I mean both the HTTP daemon *and* the webapp, in case they're separate. (Consider e.g. a regular server with Nginx and a PHP-based webapp – either Nginx *or* the webapp could serve the `WWW-Authenticate` header.)

Even if you determined that it's at least Linux-based, it is still impossible to give a precise answer just because of the huge variety of HTTP servers that exist for Linux alone (both general-purpose and oriented towards embedded devices, and of course, those handcrafted by the manufacturer).

In the simplest case with a standalone Linux web server running Apache httpd it may be in httpd.conf as a line within the VirtualHost configuration – whereas for a smaller IoT device, it might simply be defined as **part of the service's source code**, i.e. set at compilation time. So assuming you managed to extract a Linux rootfs, you would need to run `strings` against all executables you can find in that rootfs, and then you might find the realm, possibly "pre-baked" into the whole header as a single string.

(Note that the binary in question might not look like a dedicated web server – even in regular websites, it is typical for HTTP to be handled by a library pulled into the "app" itself, rather than by a standalone webserver, and I only suspect that this would be even *more* common in IoT where memory space is at a premium.)